Running PHP commands on remote server via SSH with Bitbucket pipelines
I'm setting up a Bitbucket pipeline to deploy a PHP application. The goal is to connect through SSH to a remote server, do a git pull and run a deploy_dev.sh script.
Everything is running fine, except the deploy_dev.sh script. When the pipeline executes that one, I get bash: line 1: php: command not found
PHP is installed on the remote server, and running the same command directly on the server (with the same SSH user) executes it perfectly.
I assume I don't need PHP in the docker container, when I connect via SSH on a remote server. Am I missing something else? Is there a difference between interactive & non-interactive SSH sessions? If so, how can I add PHP (and other aliasses) to the PATH?
If I echo the $PATH variable via SSH myself, I get more content & directories compared to the contents through SSH via the Bitbucket pipelines. ps: remote server is Ubuntu with Plesk on it.
Hereby my bitbucket-pipelines.yml content:
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &backend-syntax-check
        name: Searching for PHP syntax errors
        image: php:8.0-cli
        script:
          - find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^.*\.(module|install|inc|php|theme)$' | while read filename ; do php -l $filename || exit 1 ; done
    - step: &frontend-syntax-check
        name: Searching for JS and CSS syntax errors
        script:
          - npm install -g acorn
          - find web -name *.js | grep -P '^web\/(modules|themes)\/custom\/(?!(glazed|sooperthemes))' | while read filename ; do acorn --allow-hash-bang --ecma9 --silent $filename || exit 1 ; done
          - npm install -g csslint
          - find web -name *.css | grep -P '^web\/(modules|themes)\/custom\/(?!(glazed|sooperthemes))' | while read filename ; do if [ "${filename##*/}" != "bootstrap.css" ]; then csslint --quiet --format=compact --warnings=display-property-grouping,known-properties,font-faces,import,zero-utils,overqualified-elements,floats,font-sizes,ids,important,outline-none --ignore=box-model,duplicate-properties,empty-rules,adjoining-classes,box-sizing,compatible-vendor-prefixes,gradients,text-indent,vendor-prefix,fallback-colors,star-property-hack,underscore-property-hack,bulletproof-font-face,regex-selectors,universal-selector,unqualified-attributes,shorthand,duplicate-background-images,order-alphabetical,qualified-headings,unique-headings $filename || exit 1 ; fi ; done

pipelines:
  default:
    #- step: *backend-syntax-check
    #- step: *frontend-syntax-check
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to DEV
          deployment: dev
          script:
            - echo "Git pull"
            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.8.1
              variables:
                SSH_USER: $SSH_USERNAME
                SERVER: $SSH_HOSTNAME
                MODE: "command"
                #DEBUG: "true"
                COMMAND: 'php -v && cd drupal && git pull && cd scripts/deploy && ./deploy_dev.sh'
            - echo "Deploy step finished"

Thanks for any help!
I tried different commands, included a PHP docker image, validated if PHP is running on the remote server. Nothing worked, unless PHP commands can be executed properly when logging in through SSH myself (excluding Bitbucket).

Does deploy_dev.sh start with a shebang line? What is the output of which -a php?

@N1ngu: the deploy_dev.sh starts with:
#!/usr/bin/bash
The PHP path via SSH on my own laptop:
/var/www/vhosts/dev.gifthings.me/.phpenv/shims/php
